# Magento 2 admin grid not rendering

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, grid

Magento 2 admin grids are not loading. In console I'm getting the following warning message.

> No template was found by selector: null template.js:59:17

Comment: Can you please add screenshot?

Comment: sure. http://www.screencast.com/t/WAgxuQDh

Comment: Have check after running all the command like setup:upgrade,di:compile and s:s:d?